# How to schedule out a month with tasks under certain criteria?

Tags: arrays, excel, date

My scenario is that I have a list of different companies. I need to find a date within the month to upgrade them onto a new system. However, for each company, the assigned date must fit under certain criteria.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmI5Z.png)

I want to populate the Upgrade date column with an ideal date. 
The upgrade date cannot fall between the Last Old Input date and the Last Old Pay date.
The upgrade date must be between the Last Old Pay date and the First New Input date.

Complications:
    1. All companies that have the same value under Parent column must have the same upgrade date. 
    2. There are ~4 weeks in a month. I want the upgrade dates to be spread as evenly as possible throughout the weeks. So as close to 25% of all companies per week. Therefore if there are more than one viable upgrade date possibilities, try to fill out the month as evenly as possible. (If COUNT = 1/4 total companies, go to next week type deal)
    3. Within the week itself, I want the upgrade date to be the same day if possible. Example: all on Monday of that week, all on Friday of that week.

So to start:

Is there a way to create an array formula that can read each company one by one, and produce out a list of possible list of dates for that company. So for company 112, I know that 8/27-8/30 are blacked out. I know that the date should be between 8/30 and 9/10. How can I get Excel to auto-populate all the options out (8/31, 9/1, 9/2, 9/3, etc.)?
And then be able to group all companies together that are under the same Parent, and find a common upgrade date that works for all of the companies combined?

Comment: Is this specifically an Excel question? if so, please tag it as such. Also, you may get better support at https://superuser.com/ if you're not looking to code your own solution.

Comment: Beyond that, some more detail about your problem will help people give better answers. Where are your companies now? Can you give us some idea of what the data looks like and how you can access it now?